# Why data in room automatically deleted when have a new data in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I have a feature namely `draft`. I already success showing draft data from room to RV as a list. And also open that data into detail page with different id (primary key), this is a success too.

But the problem is, If I only have 1 data in the list draft, and then when I open it in detail page, it's showing. But when I have 2 data (for ex: `data 1` and `data 2`), let's say `data 1` it's `pref draft` and `data 2` it's `new draft`. Then when I open `data 1` in the detail page, the data from the room it's null/size == 0. But when I open `data 2`, the data it's not null.

So the problem is when I add a `new draft data`, the `prev data` data in the `detail page` always automatically deleted, but the `new draft data` it's not. Why it's happened?

This is my view model to show data in the list draft:

```
private val _listDraft = MutableLiveData<ResultState<List<PolicyHolderSwitchingEntity>>>()
    val listDraft: LiveData<ResultState<List<PolicyHolderSwitchingEntity>>> get() = _listDraft


    private fun setDraft(resultState: ResultState<List<PolicyHolderSwitchingEntity>>) {
        _listDraft.postValue(resultState)
    }


    private suspend fun getDraft() : List<PolicyHolderSwitchingEntity> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.getSwitchingAndRedirectionDraft()
        }
    }

    fun getListDraft() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val draft = getDraft()
            if (draft.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                setDraft(ResultState.NoData())
                return@launch
            }
            setDraft(ResultState.HasData(draft))
        }
    }
```

This is my fragment to show list draft:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.shimmerStateView.setShimmerLayout(R.layout.shimmer_list_switching_redirection)

        initRecyclerView()
        vm.getListDraft()
        vm.listDraft.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                when (it) {
                    is ResultState.NoData -> {
                        binding.shimmerStateView.showNoData(R.string.no_switching_redirection_history)
                        binding.contentGroup.gone()
                    }
                    is ResultState.HasData -> {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        binding.shimmerStateView.showHasData()
                        binding.contentGroup.visible()
                        adapter.submitList(it.data)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

And this is my view model to show data in the detail page:

```
private val _draftSwitching = SingleLiveData<ResultState<PolicyHolderSwitchingEntity>>()
    val draftSwitching: LiveData<ResultState<PolicyHolderSwitchingEntity>> get() = _draftSwitching

    private fun setDraftSwitching(resultState: ResultState<PolicyHolderSwitchingEntity>) {
        _draftSwitching.postValue(resultState)
    }

    fun getListSwitchingFromDraft(mptId: Long?) {
        viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            try {
                val switching = repository.showRecapSwitchingDraft(mptId)
                setSwitchingForm(switching.policyHolder) // this is not deleted
                setListInvestmentFund(switching.investmentFund) // but this is always deleted in the prev draft when a new draft added
                setListFundSpinner(switching.listFund) // but this is always deleted in the prev draft when a new draft added
                setDraftSwitching(ResultState.HasData(switching.policyHolder))
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                Timber.e("Error getting switching : ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my code in detail page:

```
private fun initDataListSwitchingDraft() {
        vm.getListSwitchingFromDraft(mptId?.toLong())
        vm.draftSwitching.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                when (it) {
                    is ResultState.HasData -> {
                        val data = it.data
                        showContent()
                        binding.shimmerStateView.showHasData()
                        listSpinner.add(NominalType("0", NOMINAL))
                        listSpinner.add(NominalType("1", PERCENTAGE))
                        listSpinner.add(NominalType("2", UNIT))
                        val type = data.transferFrom
                        displayDataSpinnerType(listSpinner, type)
                        displayDataSourceFund(vm.currentSource.value)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

And this is my Dao to show list draft:

```
@Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM policy_holder_switching WHERE is_draft=1")
    fun getSwitchingAndRedirectionDrafts(): List<PolicyHolderSwitchingEntity>
```

And this is my Dao to show data in detail page:

```
@Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM policy_holder_switching WHERE mptIdSwitching=:mptIdSwitching AND is_draft=1")
    fun fetchAllSwitchingFromDraft(mptIdSwitching: Long?): SwitchingFromAndDestination
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is my fault. This because I forgot to use the `primary key` as `auto-generated`.